# What is "quantum internet" and what is its relation with quantum entanglement?

Tags: entanglement, quantum-networks

In a recent news "[Scientists Make Major Breakthrough In ‘quantum Entanglement’ That Could Change How The Internet Works](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/quantum-entanglement-internet-network-memories-processors-a9332476.html)"

> Scientists have managed to entangle two "quantum memories" at a distant much bigger than ever before, a breakthrough that could one day change the way the internet works.
>
> To entangle those two quantum memories, researchers had to shoot photons, or individual particles of light, along the 50-kilometre cable.

One can think that, if one can separate quantum entangled particles then use them to transmit information between them. But the researchers entangled at the end of the cable;

> After making their way over that distance, the two memories were able to interfere with each other, making the experiment a success and demonstrating that two quantum memories could become entangled over such a distance.

My questions are;

- What is quantum internet
- What is the relation of it with quantum entanglement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quantum internet** is a theoretical concept of global (or at least wide) [quantum net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_network). It would allow to interconnect many quantum processors (or computers) and enable them to communicate each other.

**How is a entanglement related:** Quantum entanglement enables to employ [superdense coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superdense_coding) and [quantum teleportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) for a communication. The former is used for sending two classical bits over one qubit (i.e. information is compressed) but before that you have to have two entangled qubits, one placed at a sender and second one at a receiver. 
The latter allows to transport qubit through classical communication channel (two classical bits are used for that) and reconstruct its state at a receiver but again before that you need to have two entangled qubits at both sides of communication.

Comment: So, actually, in the experiment the quantum states entangled while they have a distance of 50km?

Comment: @kelalaka: Yes, it is possible. But according to the article, it seems to me that the cable was coiled in a laboratory under "ideal" conditions and this allowed to retain qubits entangled.